# Monitor many IMAP mailboxes simultaneously C#

Tags: c#, imap, mailkit

I have a .NE|T Core 3 web application that needs to monitor 1000's of mailboxes at the same time. I need to act on emails as soon as they come through. I have created a background service that loops around the mailboxes to monitor, then creates a task for each mailbox that runs for the duration of the program. The task reference is discarded within the loop but a cancellation token is passed in to clean up the event handlers and close the connection when the application stops.
I am using MailKit to monitor mailboxes using the IMAP IDLE client [see here](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/Documentation/Examples/ImapIdleExample.cs#L152).

```cs
foreach (var mailAccount in mailAccountsToMonitor)
{
    // ConcurrentDictionary
    if (mailAccountMonitorTasks.ContainsKey(mailAccount.Id)) continue;
    // NOT awaiting the result as these tasks run indefinitely and won't finish until the CancellationToken is cancelled
    _ = MonitorMailAccount(mailAccount, cancellationToken);
}
```

I have an async method which is called whenever a message comes through from a mailbox. This adds the mail item to a database and performs some other small tasks. I've tried to keep the method footprint small.

```cs
private async Task OnMessagesAddedAsync(object sender, MessagesAddedEventArgs args)
{
    // perform database insert and other conditional logic
}
```

The method above is attached as an event handler for the Idle client like so: `idleClient.MessagesAddedAsync += OnMessagesAddedAsync;`
I use an async version of an event delegate in the Idle client: `public event Func<object, MessagesAddedEventArgs, Task> MessagesAddedAsync;`

My concern is that this won't scale to thousands of mailboxes and I'm already starting to face strange issues - though this is possibly due to my lack of in-depth knowledge about multi-threading rather than an issue with this design?

What is the correct way of performing thousands of long running event driven tasks without facing things like threadpool exhaustion, socket and database exceptions etc? Is there a better way to design this than I already have?

Comment: You're right this is going to scale badly. Could you perhaps you set up a rule on the mailserver which forwards all mail to a single inbox which you can then monitor with your code? Or what about just checking each mailbox periodically, on rotation? You say the mails need to be actioned "as soon as they come through"...but realistically how slow a response would be acceptable, before it has an adverse impact on whatever service you're providing? What volume of mail are you expecting from each mailbox, and at what frequency?

Comment: It may not scale well, but thousands is not a lot. Millions is a lot. Hitting scaling problem at four digits with this sort of design is early, so I'd look at the concrete problems you're seeing rather than questioning your overall design.

Comment: @ADyson I would imagine we'd be looking at a few hundred to 1k emails per mailbox a day? I think 5 minutes would be the absolute maximum we'd be willing to wait before acting on an incoming email because the actions we take on the emails are time sensitive but a loop might work. We won't be in control of some mailservers so forwarding rules are likely out not possible.

Comment: @arnt Yes you are probably right, I will review the code to identify any immediate improvements.

Comment: Look out for other kinds of resources you might run out of. Like caches that work well for small loads, or the number of database backends, or NAT middleboxes that won't deal with thousands of open TCP connections.